# Install Ubuntu On Previous Installation

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation, permissions

I posted this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885916/16-04-just-stopped-working-screen-full-of-errors) a fortnight ago when I installed `lamp` and mucked up the permission rights which (I suspect) is responsible for the boot error screen above.

I have been using Windows10 since and am desperate to get back to Ubuntu (*insert sad emoji here*). I wonder, can I install new Ubuntu on the same partition and somehow have the previous files still available?

I am mainly interested in the 'www', 'document', 'download' folders.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just copy them to a USB and add them back after the installation?

Comment: yes, always an option, except I dont have big enough a usb.

Comment: I think Mark Kirby's suggestion is the best option here. Use an Ubuntu Live USB to look at the files and copy them to somewhere safe (another USB stick or even to the Windows 10 partition if you prefer). If there's a lot of problems with your previous Ubuntu installation then it's a lot easier to start with a fresh install than chase down all the errors and try to find a way to fix them. Don't forget to boot your live USB in UEFI mode if Windows is set up with UEFI already.

Comment: @pHeLiOn & Mark thanks for the suggestion, I guess thats what will have to do.